# Practical Effect of Time-Decay on Variance Swaps?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, vix, theta, variance-swap

I want to implement a long vol hedging strategy by rolling spot variance swaps every month. This would be done through replicating spot VIX using the definition of VIX as a portfolio of OTM one-month calls/puts weighted by the inverse square of their strikes.  In addition to transaction costs, I've read that time decay can be a problem for similar strategies (e.g. long strangles).

Does anyone have an intuition (either through experience or academic research) as to what extent time decay should lower the payout compared to the theoretical payout for the swap?